# place text at bottom in right aligned div container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an imprint footer which places the copyright container at the right side on larger screen sizes.

As long as the copyright is aligned at the right side I want its text being aligned vertically at the bottom.

How can I achieve that? I tried `vertical-align:bottom` but this did not help.

**Note**:
You might have to open the snippet on full screen because the flexbox gets removed on lower screen sizes.

```css
#imprint {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #2f333b;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#imprintContainer {
  display: flex;
}

#imprintContainer .imprintItem:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #29abe2;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #3abcf3;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  #imprint {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  #imprintContainer {
    display: block;
  }
  #imprintContainer .imprintItem:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="imprint">
  <div id="imprintContainer">

    <div class="imprintItem">
      <p>Company</p>
      <p>Street
        <br>City</p>
    </div>

    <div class="imprintItem">
      <p>
        <a class="link" href="mailto:test">Email</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        Read our
        <a class="link" href="/privacy">Privacy</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="imprintItem">
    <p>
      © Copyright 2018
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this style:

```
.imprintItem.copy{
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

And then add 'copy' as a class for the copyright div.

Answer (score 2):

Use `align-self` with the copyright element

```css
#imprint {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #2f333b;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#imprintContainer {
  display: flex;
}
.imprintItem {
 align-self:flex-end;
}

#imprintContainer .imprintItem:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #29abe2;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #3abcf3;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  #imprint {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  #imprintContainer {
    display: block;
  }
  #imprintContainer .imprintItem:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="imprint">
  <div id="imprintContainer">

    <div class="imprintItem">
      <p>Company</p>
      <p>Street
        <br>City</p>
    </div>

    <div class="imprintItem">
      <p>
        <a class="link" href="mailto:test">Email</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        Read our
        <a class="link" href="/privacy">Privacy</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="imprintItem">
    <p>
      © Copyright 2018
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer :p

Answer (score 1):

Try this setup. Changes I made: I added `copyrightHolder` as class to the
 `<div>` that contains the copyright paragraph.
For the copyright paragraph, I added `copyright` id. See CSS for style definition
 As indicated in the question: expand the demo below to full screen in order for `flex` to be seen in action.

```css
.copyrightHolder {
position: relative;
}

#copyright {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#imprint {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #2f333b;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#imprintContainer {
  display: flex;
}

#imprintContainer .imprintItem:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #29abe2;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #3abcf3;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  #imprint {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  #imprintContainer {
    display: block;
  }
  #imprintContainer .imprintItem:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="imprint">
  <div id="imprintContainer">

    <div class="imprintItem">
      <p>Company</p>
      <p>Street
        <br>City</p>
    </div>

    <div class="imprintItem">
      <p>
        <a class="link" href="mailto:test">Email</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        Read our
        <a class="link" href="/privacy">Privacy</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="imprintItem copyrightHolder">
    <p id="copyright">
      © Copyright 2018
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solutions. But i think. All u do here... Use flex for this thing isn't the best solution.

```css
#imprint {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #2f333b;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#imprintContainer {
  display: flex;
}

#imprintContainer .imprintItem:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#imprint > .imprintItem {
  position:relative;
}

#imprint > .imprintItem p {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #29abe2;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #3abcf3;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  #imprint {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  #imprintContainer {
    display: block;
  }
  #imprintContainer .imprintItem:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="imprint">
  <div id="imprintContainer">

    <div class="imprintItem">
      <p>Company</p>
      <p>Street
        <br>City</p>
    </div>

    <div class="imprintItem">
      <p>
        <a class="link" href="mailto:test">Email</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        Read our
        <a class="link" href="/privacy">Privacy</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="imprintItem">
    <p>
      © Copyright 2018
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

...Now i saw.. the first answer is the same... But in my code. U dont have to change the html^^